# How to create StaticFileHandler for Django Admin using Tornado with python manage.py collectstatic

Tags: python, django, tornado

having done `python manage.py collectstatic` for my Django application I copied the admin assets into the static folder. However when it comes time to view the admin module in the Django application the assets aren't viewable and instead I see a 404 GET trace back to the admin assts. These are the current Handlers that I have registered with the Tornado application that I am deploying:

```
  ('/hello-tornado', HelloHandler),
  (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "/home/django-tornado-demo-master/testsite/static"}),
  ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
```

These is the file tree of my statics folder:

```
static
└── admin
    ├── css
    ├── img
    │   └── gis
    └── js
        └── admin
```

How can I modify the Static File handler to load the assets that I have in this tree structure? Thanks for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out that my problem was that the static directory referenced the wrong  Django project.